# Code First Migrations with Entity Framework - Moving to a test server, how?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC4 application and am a complete newbie to the concept of database migrations and how they are implemented.  So far in development we have been using the built in localdb capabilities of VS2012 and everything's been good.  My question is, how do I go about moving these to a separate SQL server on a test environment?  I haven't been able to find a good explanation and was hoping you folks could tip me off to the proper way to do this.

I know it's possible to generate SQL scripts locally and run them manually on the server, but ideally I would really like to simply be able to run the migrations (via powershell or cmd) on the test server and have it apply all the needed changes to the SQL Server database.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you not just change the connection string in your web.config?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Once I go ahead and change the database connection string how would I execute the update-database command without Visual Studio Package Manager?

Comment: ...a little more background:

Comment: I am currently pulling from git and building with msbuild, so it would be really nice if there was an easy way that I could fire off the update-database command via a script.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? You should use the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for local development and the migrations are working fine there.  I was wondering if it was possible to not use this on the server.  Ideally I would not like to jump through all the security hoops every time I want to update the dev server.

Comment: Do you know of any way of running this without the package manager console on server?

Comment: You'd have to generate the scripts using Visual Studio, then run those on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this using the migrate.exe tool, a command line tool installed when you pull in the EF5 nuget package to your solution.

There is a good overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) and [here](http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2012/03/13/Automating-EF-43x-Data-Migrations-in-your-Build.aspx), and plenty of other resources on the web for this.

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I was looking for and solves the scripting problem perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is nearly link-only and should be improved by moving more information regarding the use of migrate.exe into the local answer, to protect against content degradation or removal at link targets.